# Install MySQL Automatically on WIN, Linux, macOS

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, electron

I want to use MySQL for an electron app in production and thus, if the client machine doesn't has MySQL already installed on it, then the app will not be able to function. So, is there any way to execute a auto-install MySQL script that installs MySQL on the client machine, even if its not already installed.

Since the app has to be cross-platform, so I am looking for a standard or minimum effort procedure (to speed up the process) to achieve the above, during first-time-app-startup on Windows7+, Ubuntu 14+ and macOS.

I found the following ways to auto-install:

1. Windows : [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-installer-msi-quiet.html)
2. Linux & macOS: Create a bash script that runs before first-time-startup of the app. (Although, it will check whether MySQL instance is already present on the machine or not)

Looking for a better option than the above mentioned ones.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider the [BitNami MySQL](https://bitnami.com/stack/mysql) distribution; I have always used their VMs when I went after their products, but stand-alone installers are offered for most platforms (including Linux).

(Edit: It seems that the installer for MySQL is offered only for Linux x64)

Comment: Yes, but here the situation is to make a cross-platform app with atleast 3 major OSes.

Comment: There is also the possibility to have an unattended VirtualBox install to be bundled with a MySQL-only VM. It may be overkill though

Comment: You can install `XAMPP`. It will give you the options for mySQL